# In Vue.js, how can I restore data binding after changing DOM through vanilla js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

we have code like this:

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="showInfo">{{ text }}</button>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    text: 'user info'
  },
  methods: {
    showInfo(event) {
      var $btn = event.target
      http.get($btn, '/user/13')
    }
})
```

part of `http.get()`, basically it just gives the button a loader img, calls api, and restores the button when the api returns success.

```js
http = {
  get(el, url) {
    var old = el.innerHTML
    el.innerHTML = '<img src="loading.gif" width="20"/>'
    whateverAjax(url, () => {
      el.innerHTML = old
    })
  },
  // ...
}
```

then after clicked the button once, change `text` to something else, say "log in", the button's text won't update.

Is there a way to make it bind with the `text` again?

Comment: I would not recommend doing separate vanilla operations on templates already being watched by Vue. I highly advise handling this gif loading logic inside Vue

Answer (score 0):

I assuming than you want put spinner image as content of your button while wait for data from your back-end, then according Vue ecosystem you could apply this logic:

- When the `button` is clicked it call the method `showInfo()`, there
  the property `isLoading` is setted to `true`, then in the template i
  binding the attribute class using [conditional assign](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html), this mean
  if the property `isLoading` is `true` will put the css class called
  `"loader"`(this class have styles for spinner animation).
- After the method `fetchData()` is called to simulate to fetch data
  from your back-end, when this response is finalized the property
  `isLoading` is setted to `false`, this will remove the class in
  button.
- Same logic for the attribute "disabled".

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    text: 'user info',
    isLoading: false,
  },
  methods: {
    showInfo() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.fetchData()
        .then(() => {
          /* do something */
        })
        .catch(() => {
          /* handle error */
        })
        .finally(() => (this.isLoading = false));
    },
    fetchData() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), 2000);
      });
    },
  },
});
```

```css
button{padding:1em}.loader,.loader:after{border-radius:50%;width:5em;height:5em}.loader{font-size:10px;position:relative;text-indent:-9999em;border-top:1.1em solid rgba(255,255,255,.2);border-right:1.1em solid rgba(255,255,255,.2);border-bottom:1.1em solid rgba(255,255,255,.2);border-left:1.1em solid #fff;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);-ms-transform:translateZ(0);transform:translateZ(0);-webkit-animation:load8 1.1s infinite linear;animation:loading 1.1s infinite linear}@-webkit-keyframes loading{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);transform:rotate(0)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}}@keyframes loading{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);transform:rotate(0)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button 
    :class="{loader: isLoading}" 
    @click="showInfo"
    :disabled="isLoading"
  >
    {{ text }}
  </button>
</div>
```